# dhtmlx combo, autocomplete mode, js

Tags: autocomplete, combobox, dhtmlx

I am having problem with autocomplete mode with dhtmlx combo.

The includes files are as follows:

```
    // Images
    <script>
      window.dhx_globalImgPath="combo/dhtmlxCombo/codebase/imgs/";
    </script>

    // CSS 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="combo/dhtmlxCombo/codebase/dhtmlxcombo.css">

    // Required JS files
    <script src="combo/dhtmlxCombo/codebase/dhtmlxcommon.js"></script>
    <script src="combo/dhtmlxCombo/codebase/dhtmlxcombo.js"></script>
    <script src="combo/dhtmlxCombo/codebase/ext/dhtmlxcombo_extra.js"></script>
```

I have no issues with the code above and works well.

The  following code I have on the page I have the combo itself is as follows:

```
    <!-- HTML Combo -->
    <div id="pickup" style="width:260px;"></div>

    <!-- Initialisation of combo -->
    <script>
    var x = new dhtmlXCombo("pickup",260,"image");

          // this works
          x.loadXML("list.xml");
          x.enableFilteringMode(true); 
    </script>
```

My problem is i want to use autocomplete mode by using the following line of code:

```
    x.enableFilteringMode(true, "list.xml", true, true)
```

When i try the above line, it doesnt give error but it doesnt filter either. However im told to use a php file but i don't know what I need to put in the list.php file itself. I can code just dont know what to put in. Can anyone shed some light, the docs arent that helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**enableFilteringMode** enables server-side filtering. It means that when you type something in the combo header, this text is sent to the script that is defined the second parameter of the method. The script generates XML with options that correspond the mask. 
Therefore, you can't use static XML in this case.

You can find a demo of the dynamic loading in the dhtmlxCombo package:
dhtmlxCombo/samples/04_filtering/01_combo_big_db.html

Also, you can use [dhtmlxConnector](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxConnector/index.shtml) that provides a ready solutions for the server side (PHP, ASP.NET, etc.). The dhtmlxConnector package includes a demo with dhtmlxCombo, e.g.:
dhtmlxConnector_php_v10_110725/php/samples/combo/02_sql.html